# animation triggers on load, animate to default state when class removed

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm doing an animation that gets triggered with adding a class to a element. Now on removal of the class I want the animation to go the other way, I figured out to how to reverse the animation, the problem is onload that it triggers it. What can I do to prevent it, what can I change, what am I missing?

the full html/css/js are in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lugnmmpe/5/)

here are the good parts,

```
@keyframes expand {
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 5rem;
  }
  70%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes contract {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -6rem);
    width: 5rem;
  }
}

[data-am-button~="buy"] {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    transform: translate(0, -6rem);
    width: 5rem;
    animation: contract 500ms forwards;

    span {
        display: none;
    }

    .is-expanded & {
        animation: expand 500ms forwards;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of putting the animation on the button by default. Add the animation to a `.is-contracted` class.

Then toggle between these 2 classes when clicking the button. This means that nothing is animated on the page load. Only the button clicking.

CSS changes:

```
[data-am-button~="buy"] {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    transform: translate(0, -6rem);
    width: 5rem;
  //animation: contract 500ms forwards;             <-- Removed this

    span {
        display: none;
    }

    .is-expanded & {
        animation: expand 500ms forwards;
    }
  .is-contracted & {
    animation: contract 500ms forwards;//    <-- added it to this new class
   }
```

JS changes:

```
$('.js-expander').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parents('.product-info');
  if ( $parent.hasClass('is-expanded') ){
       $parent.removeClass('is-expanded')
       $parent.addClass('is-contracted')
  } else {
         $parent.addClass('is-expanded')
       $parent.removeClass('is-contracted')
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/Lugnmmpe/7/